# jBCrypt checkpw returns false for correct password

Tags: java, jbcrypt

I am hashing the password "password" using JBCrypt by doing

```
public User addUser(User newUser) {
        String passwordHash = BCrypt.hashpw(newUser.getPassword(), BCrypt.gensalt());
        newUser.setPassword(passwordHash);
        Object<User> user = new ObjectImpl<User>();
        return user.addObject(User.class, newUser);
    }
```

In the above, the `newUser` is delivered through a JAX-RS Restful web service.

In a `ContextRequestFilter` I'm trying to authenticate user as below:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "Basic ";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        List<String> authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaders().get(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
        if (authorizationHeader != null) {
            String authorizationToken = authorizationHeader.get(0);
            authorizationToken = authorizationToken.replaceFirst(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME, "");
            String decodedString = Base64.decodeAsString(authorizationToken);
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(decodedString, ":");
            try {
                String username = tokenizer.nextToken();
                String password = tokenizer.nextToken();
                Object<User> userObject = new ObjectImpl<User>();
                User user = userObject.getObjectByNamedQuery("User.byEmail", username);
                String hashedPassword = user.getPassword();
                if (BCrypt.checkpw(password, hashedPassword)) {
                    return;
                }
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                abortRequest(requestContext);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                abortRequest(requestContext);
            }
        }
        abortRequest(requestContext);
    }
```

Here, when I send the password as "password", the `abortRequest` method still fires. I see that `BCrypt.checkpw(password, hashedPassword)` is returning `false`.

Comment: That means you need to start debugging. Does bcrypt work in a simple test where you hash a password and then verify it immediately. The anser is probably yes. Once you've checked that, it means the problem is in your code. What is the value of the password after generation? What is the value of the password when you get it when verifying it? Are you sure you don't have invisible white spaces around the password?

Comment: I checked the length of the hash when I first hashed it and before saving to db. Then I checked the hash size again before I ran `checkpw`. Both show a length of 60. I also checked the length of the plaintext password which shows 8 as it should. Any, ideas?

Comment: What about checking the values of the hash? What about chceking the values of the plain text passwords? Have you written a test checking thet bcrypt works as you expect?

Comment: You were right... `getPassword()` method of `newUser` was annotated with `@XmlTransient` which was making the password `null` at the time of hashing. Changing this to `@XmlReadOnly` fixed the issue. Thanks for the ideas.